# Encoding unicode with 'utf-8' shows byte-strings only for non-ascii

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I'm running python2.7.10

Trying to wrap my head around why the following behavior is seen. (Sure there is a reasonable explanation)

So I define two unicode characters, with only the first one in the ascii-set, and the second one outside of it.

```
>>> a=u'\u0041'
>>> b=u'\u1234'
>>> print a
A
>>> print b
ሴ
```

Now I encode it to see what the corresponding bytes would be. But only the latter gives me the results I am expecting to see (bytes)

```
>>> a.encode('utf-8')
'A'
>>> b.encode('utf-8')
'\xe1\x88\xb4'
```

Perhaps the issue is in my expectation, and if so, one of you can explain where the flaw lies.
 - My a,b are unicodes (hex values of the ordinals inside)
 - When I print these, the interpreter prints the actual character corresponding to each unicode byte.
 - When I encode, I assumed that it would be converted into a byte-string using the encoding scheme I provide (in this case utf-8). I expected to see a bytestring for a.encode, just like I did for b.encode.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no flaw. You encoded to UTF-8, which uses the same bytes as the ASCII standard for the first 127 codepoints of the Unicode standard, and uses multiple bytes (between 2 and 4) for everything else.

You then echoed that value in your terminal, which uses the `repr()` function to build a *debugging representation*. That representation produces a valid Python expression for strings, one that is *ASCII safe*. Any bytes in that value that is not *printable* as an ASCII character, is shown as an escape sequence. Thus UTF-8 bytes are shown as `\xhh` hex escapes.

Most importantly, because `A` is a printable ASCII character, it is shown as is; any code editor or terminal will accept ASCII, and for most English text showing the actual text is so much more useful.

Note that you used *`print`* for the `unicode` values stored in `a` and `b`, which means Python encodes those values to your terminal codec, coordinating with your terminal to produce the right output. You did not echo the values in the interpreter. Had you done so, you'd also seen debug output:

```
>>> a = u'\u0041'
>>> b = u'\u1234'
>>> a
u'A'
>>> b
u'\u1234'
```

In Python 3, the functionality of the `repr()` function (or rather, the `object.__repr__` hook) has been updated to produce a `unicode` string with most printable codepoints left un-escaped. Use the new `ascii()` function to get the above behaviour.

Comment: Makes total sense. Thank you. Is there a way to print escape sequences \xhh for the ascii safe code points just like  the non-printable ones?

Comment: @ajaysdesk: you'll have to do so manually. You could use the `binascii.hexlify()` function for example, to convert all bytes to hex output (but without the `\x` prefixes).

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I wanted